# Error "'let' cannot appear nested inside another 'var' or 'let' pattern"

Tags: swift

Having following struct I am getting error "'let' cannot appear nested inside another 'var' or 'let' pattern":

```
struct test {
    let name: String,
    let dictionary: [String: String]
}
```

When changed to `var` the error is similar - "'var' cannot appear nested inside another 'var' or 'let' pattern":

```
struct test {
   var name: String,
   var dictionary: [String: String]
}
```

Having only the `dictionary` both `var` and `let` works fine:

```
struct test {
   var dictionary: [String: String]
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: I would not say that this error is "caused by typos." The extraneous commas are something that's required in other languages, and while they're a mistake in Swift, they're not likely something that the OP included accidentally. This is a common error, and it's exactly the kind of question that could help other users, whereas the 'not reproducible or caused by typo' close reason is meant for questions that are unlikely to every help anyone else. Voting to reopen, and also voting up because the OP did a great job writing a clear, concise question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a redundant comma after `var name: String`, when removed all works fine:

```
struct test {
    let name: String
    let dictionary: [String: String]
}
```